# Listening to release asset changes with Github webhooks

Tags: github, webhooks

I have automated my Github releases with Grunt (https://github.com/hypeJunction/deploy_test/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) and currently trying to deploy a webhook when the new release is made.

The problem that I am facing is that the Grunt script needs more time to upload a .zip asset than it takes Github to issue a webhook. My webhook listener issues a request to Github API to retrieve latest release info, but the assets are not yet available for download. If I manually trigger webhook redelivery, the request succeeds.

Is there a way to delay a Github hook, or do I need to implement a delay in my listener (would rather not make it async)?

Comment: Here is the service I am working on [Elgg community plugins](https://github.com/hypeJunction/community_plugins/commit/b79a50635b58f970992c9f25ad01a5715ef3c588#diff-6549418dbed4b36153f7f1f45f9992c8R473)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Github.

> No, there's no way to delay a webhook on our end -- you'd need to do
>   it on your end.
>
> Another workaround might be that you create a draft release first,
>   then upload all the assets, and the publish the release (by updating
>   it via the API). The release webhook is triggered only when the
>   release is published, so this should allow you to trigger the webhook
>   only after all assets are available.
>
> Hope this helps.